# Deploy Ember App Kit App via PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, ember.js

How can I deploy an App developed on Ember App [Kit](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/) through a PhoneGap wrapper?

It was suggested that [this](https://github.com/ianpetzer/ember_phonegap_starter) is the way to go here and that doing so would be trivial but I can find no documentation on how this could be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have used https://build.phonegap.com/ with emberjs apps plenty of times and works nicely.

Once you have your `emberjs` app running just follow the steps mentioned in build.phonegap. Simply archive your application containing `index` and `resource` files to a `zip` file and upload.

Regarding the packaging a quick approach is to download a demo phonegap app https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world
place the emberjs dist files (for quick access just use the results from an http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ ) in a folder along with the contents from the www folder of the demo app  (to be honest i actually removed the original js and spec folders found inside the demo app). Create a zip file and upload it for build at phonegap.

Comment: There must be a lot more to it than that.  Easily get an ember app running, but as of yet I've been unsuccessful in deploying an ember app with phonegap build.

Comment: @carter i have actually done this process and still doing it and works perfectly, please explain what problems you are facing or even better post a separate question.

Comment: @carter also edited the answer with specific description for quick packaging. It has been tested with latest version of ember (currently 1.9.1 and hbs 2.0.0) and phonegap (3.6.3).

Comment: I'm using ember-cli and adobe phone gap cloud build. Ember never boots up.